# How to perform a function for a certain time period in python?

Tags: python, function, time, execution

I have a function:

```
perform(val)
```

I want to call it twice like this:

```
perform(True)
perform(False)
```

Here I want the first function call `perform(True)` to be executed for 5 hours. After 5 hours, as soon as last statement in `perform(True)` is executed, it must return, and `perform(False)` must be executed.

Something similar to this:

```
while passed_time < 5:00:
    perform(True)
perform(False)
```

Or maybe definition of `perform(val)` should be changed?

```
def perform(val):
    while passed_time < 5:00
        do_something1()
        do_something2()
        do_something3()
        do_something4()

    return
```

How can I do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.now()
while datetime.now() - start < timedelta(seconds=5*60*60):
    perform(True)
perform(False)
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is to use datetime.utcnow, that way you won't run into any problems if you cross a daylight savings boundary.